# creating the table and put data in word by excel vba shows error

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

hi i am creating vb code to create table in word  but i got error "object required" on `objTb1`
i already give `Dim objTb1 as object` so how to solve this plz help
here is my code

```
Sub Create_Table_In_Word()
Dim objWord As Object
Dim objDoc As Object
Dim objTbl As Object
Dim objRow As Object
Dim objCol As Object
Dim lngCols As Long
Dim lngRows As Long
Dim I As Long

lngCols = 2
lngRows = 4


 Range("M7").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(MID(RC[-12],SEARCH("":-"",RC[-12],1)+3,LEN(RC[-12]))=""Additional Classroom M.L."",""ACR M.L."",IF(MID(RC[-12],SEARCH("":-"",RC[-12],1)+3,LEN(RC[-12]))=""Pathya Pustak Mandal"",""PPM"",IF(MID(RC[-12],SEARCH("":-"",RC[-12],1)+3,LEN(RC[-12]))=""Toilet Block ( Boys)"",""Boy’s T.B."",IF(MID(RC[-12],SEARCH("":-"",RC[-12],1)+3,LEN(RC[-12]))=""Toilet Block ( Girls)"",""Girl’s T.B."",""""))))"
ActiveSheet.Range("A8", Range("L65536").End(xlUp)).AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:="<>"
Range("I8").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Do Until ActiveCell.EntireRow.Hidden = False
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

objWord.Visible = True

Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add(DocumentType:=0)
With objDoc.Styles(wdStyleNormal).Font
    If .NameFarEast = .NameAscii Then
        .NameAscii = ""
End If
    .NameFarEast = ""
    End With

With objDoc.PageSetup
    .LineNumbering.Active = False
    .Orientation = wdOrientPortrait
    .TopMargin = CentimetersToPoints(1.25)
    .BottomMargin = CentimetersToPoints(2.54)
    .LeftMargin = CentimetersToPoints(2.54)
    .RightMargin = CentimetersToPoints(2.54)
    .Gutter = CentimetersToPoints(0)
    .HeaderDistance = CentimetersToPoints(1.25)
    .FooterDistance = CentimetersToPoints(1.25)
    .PageWidth = CentimetersToPoints(21)
    .PageHeight = CentimetersToPoints(29.7)
    .FirstPageTray = wdPrinterDefaultBin
    .OtherPagesTray = wdPrinterDefaultBin
    .SectionStart = wdSectionNewPage
    .OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = False
    .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = False
    .VerticalAlignment = wdAlignVerticalTop
    .SuppressEndnotes = False
    .MirrorMargins = False
    .TwoPagesOnOne = False
    .BookFoldPrinting = False
    .BookFoldRevPrinting = False
    .BookFoldPrintingSheets = 1
    .GutterPos = wdGutterPosLeft
    .SectionDirection = wdSectionDirectionLtr
End With

Set objTbl = objDoc.Tables.Add(Range:=objDoc.Paragraphs(1).Range, NumRows:=lngRows, NumColumns:=lngCols)
With objTb1
        If .Style <> "Table Grid" Then
        .Style = "Table Grid"
    End If
    .ApplyStyleHeadingRows = False
    .ApplyStyleLastRow = False
    .ApplyStyleFirstColumn = False
    .ApplyStyleLastColumn = False
    .ApplyStyleRowBands = True
    .ApplyStyleColumnBands = False
End With
With objTb1.Rows
    .WrapAroundText = True
    .HorizontalPosition = wdTableCenter
    .RelativeHorizontalPosition = wdRelativeHorizontalPositionMargin
    .DistanceLeft = CentimetersToPoints(0.32)
    .DistanceRight = CentimetersToPoints(0.32)
    .VerticalPosition = CentimetersToPoints(1)
    .RelativeVerticalPosition = wdRelativeVerticalPositionMargin
    .DistanceTop = CentimetersToPoints(0)
    .DistanceBottom = CentimetersToPoints(0)
    .AllowOverlap = True
End With
objTb1.Style = "Grid Table 3 - Accent 6"
    objTb1.ApplyStyleHeadingRows = Not objTb1.ApplyStyleHeadingRows
objTb1.ApplyStyleFirstColumn = Not objTb1.ApplyStyleFirstColumn
'Selection.Tables(1)
objTb1.Select
objTb1.Columns.PreferredWidthType = wdPreferredWidthPoints
objTb1.Columns.PreferredWidth = CentimetersToPoints(9)
objTb1.Rows.Item(1).Height = CentimetersToPoints(1.2)
objTb1.Rows.Item(2).Height = CentimetersToPoints(10.2)
objTb1.Rows.Item(3).Height = CentimetersToPoints(1.2)
objTb1.Rows.Item(4).Height = CentimetersToPoints(10.2)

For I = 1 To 3
If I = 2 Then GoTo nextcell
sname = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -6).Value
tname = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -7).Value
dt = ActiveCell.Value
LOW = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
act = Range("M7").Value



 'Set objRow = objTbl.Rows(I)
    Set objRow = objTbl.Rows(I)
    Set objCol = objRow.Cells(1)
    objCol.Range.Text = "Name of School: " & sname & vbNewLine & "Taluka: " & tname

    Set objRow = objTbl.Rows(I)
    Set objCol = objRow.Cells(2)
    objCol.Range.Text = "Date: " & dt & vbNewLine & "Level of Work: " & LOW & vbNewLine & "Activity: " & act


nextcell:
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Do Until ActiveCell.EntireRow.Hidden = False
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop
Next I

Set objCol = Nothing

Set objRow = Nothing

Set objDoc = Nothing

Set objWord = Nothing


End Sub
```

**Edit 1**

Sorry my mistake
there are two variable  one is `objTb1` and other is `objTbl` so i replaced them by `objtb` so no confusion at all

**Edit 2**

i am adding image in table so i added a code

```
For x = 1 To 2
If x = 1 Then
imgx = img1
Else
imgx = img2
End If
objtb.Cell(I + 1, x).Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture imgx
With Selection
.ShapeRange.RelativeHorizontalPosition = 
wdRelativeHorizontalPositionColumn
.ShapeRange.RelativeVerticalPosition = wdRelativeVerticalPositionParagraph
.ShapeRange.RelativeHorizontalSize = wdRelativeHorizontalSizeMargin
.ShapeRange.RelativeVerticalSize = wdRelativeVerticalSizeMargin
.ShapeRange.Left = CentimetersToPoints(0.23)
.ShapeRange.LeftRelative = wdShapePositionRelativeNone
.ShapeRange.Top = CentimetersToPoints(0.05)
.ShapeRange.TopRelative = wdShapePositionRelativeNone
.ShapeRange.WidthRelative = wdShapeSizeRelativeNone
.ShapeRange.HeightRelative = wdShapeSizeRelativeNone
.ShapeRange.LockAnchor = False
.ShapeRange.LayoutInCell = True
.ShapeRange.WrapFormat.AllowOverlap = True
.ShapeRange.WrapFormat.Side = wdWrapBoth
.ShapeRange.WrapFormat.DistanceTop = CentimetersToPoints(0)
.ShapeRange.WrapFormat.DistanceBottom = CentimetersToPoints(0)
.ShapeRange.WrapFormat.DistanceLeft = CentimetersToPoints(0.32)
.ShapeRange.WrapFormat.DistanceRight = CentimetersToPoints(0.32)
.ShapeRange.WrapFormat.Type = 3
.ShapeRange.ZOrder 4
End With
Next x
```

after the put data in row 
and it show error object doesn't support property or method
in line `with selection
.ShapeRange.RelativeHorizontalPosition = 
    wdRelativeHorizontalPositionColumn`
so plz help

Comment: You are setting the `objTbl` and then using `objTb1`. Can you see the difference? there is a **1** in the name instead of **l**. Using `Option Explicit` can reduce these errors

Comment: i just check the code and i found this mistake so i edit in my question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

so i figure out the problem so final code is here

```
Option Explicit
Sub Create_Table_In_Word()
Dim objWord As Object
Dim objDoc As Object
Dim objtb As Object
Dim objRow As Object
Dim objCol As Object
Dim lngCols As Long
Dim lngRows As Long
Dim I As Long
Dim sname As Variant
Dim tname As Variant
Dim dt As Variant
Dim LOW As Variant
Dim act As Variant


lngCols = 2
lngRows = 4


Range("M7").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(MID(RC[-12],SEARCH("":-"",RC[-12],1)+3,LEN(RC[-12]))=""Additional Classroom M.L."",""ACR M.L."",IF(MID(RC[-12],SEARCH("":-"",RC[-12],1)+3,LEN(RC[-12]))=""Pathya Pustak Mandal"",""PPM"",IF(MID(RC[-12],SEARCH("":-"",RC[-12],1)+3,LEN(RC[-12]))=""Toilet Block ( Boys)"",""Boy’s T.B."",IF(MID(RC[-12],SEARCH("":-"",RC[-12],1)+3,LEN(RC[-12]))=""Toilet Block ( Girls)"",""Girl’s T.B."",""""))))"
ActiveSheet.Range("A8", Range("L65536").End(xlUp)).AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:="<>"
Range("I8").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Do Until ActiveCell.EntireRow.Hidden = False
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

objWord.Visible = True

Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add(DocumentType:=0)
With objDoc.Styles(wdStyleNormal).Font
    If .NameFarEast = .NameAscii Then
        .NameAscii = ""
End If
    .NameFarEast = ""
    End With

With objDoc.PageSetup
    .LineNumbering.Active = False
    .Orientation = wdOrientPortrait
    .TopMargin = CentimetersToPoints(1.25)
    .BottomMargin = CentimetersToPoints(2.54)
    .LeftMargin = CentimetersToPoints(2.54)
    .RightMargin = CentimetersToPoints(2.54)
    .Gutter = CentimetersToPoints(0)
    .HeaderDistance = CentimetersToPoints(1.25)
    .FooterDistance = CentimetersToPoints(1.25)
    .PageWidth = CentimetersToPoints(21)
    .PageHeight = CentimetersToPoints(29.7)
    .FirstPageTray = wdPrinterDefaultBin
    .OtherPagesTray = wdPrinterDefaultBin
    .SectionStart = wdSectionNewPage
    .OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = False
    .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = False
    .VerticalAlignment = wdAlignVerticalTop
    .SuppressEndnotes = False
    .MirrorMargins = False
    .TwoPagesOnOne = False
    .BookFoldPrinting = False
    .BookFoldRevPrinting = False
    .BookFoldPrintingSheets = 1
    .GutterPos = wdGutterPosLeft
    .SectionDirection = wdSectionDirectionLtr
End With

Set objtb = objDoc.Tables.Add(Range:=objDoc.Paragraphs(1).Range, NumRows:=lngRows, NumColumns:=lngCols)
With objtb
        If .Style <> "Table Grid" Then
        .Style = "Table Grid"
    End If
    .ApplyStyleHeadingRows = False
    .ApplyStyleLastRow = False
    .ApplyStyleFirstColumn = False
    .ApplyStyleLastColumn = False
    .ApplyStyleRowBands = True
    .ApplyStyleColumnBands = False
End With
With objtb.Rows
    .WrapAroundText = True
    .HorizontalPosition = wdTableCenter
    .RelativeHorizontalPosition = wdRelativeHorizontalPositionMargin
    .DistanceLeft = CentimetersToPoints(0.32)
    .DistanceRight = CentimetersToPoints(0.32)
    .VerticalPosition = CentimetersToPoints(1)
    .RelativeVerticalPosition = wdRelativeVerticalPositionMargin
    .DistanceTop = CentimetersToPoints(0)
    .DistanceBottom = CentimetersToPoints(0)
    .AllowOverlap = True
End With
objtb.Style = "Grid Table 3 - Accent 6"
    objtb.ApplyStyleHeadingRows = Not objtb.ApplyStyleHeadingRows
objtb.ApplyStyleFirstColumn = Not objtb.ApplyStyleFirstColumn
'Selection.Tables(1)
objtb.Select
objtb.Columns.PreferredWidthType = wdPreferredWidthPoints
objtb.Columns.PreferredWidth = CentimetersToPoints(9)
objtb.Rows.Item(1).Height = CentimetersToPoints(1.2)
objtb.Rows.Item(2).Height = CentimetersToPoints(10.2)
objtb.Rows.Item(3).Height = CentimetersToPoints(1.2)
objtb.Rows.Item(4).Height = CentimetersToPoints(10.2)

For I = 1 To 3
If I = 2 Then GoTo nextcell
sname = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -6).Value
tname = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -7).Value
dt = ActiveCell.Value
LOW = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
act = Range("M7").Value



 'Set objRow = objTbl.Rows(I)
    Set objRow = objtb.Rows(I)
    Set objCol = objRow.Cells(1)
    objCol.Range.Text = "Name of School: " & sname & vbNewLine & "Taluka: " & tname

    Set objRow = objtb.Rows(I)
    Set objCol = objRow.Cells(2)
    objCol.Range.Text = "Date: " & dt & vbNewLine & "Level of Work: " & LOW & vbNewLine & "Activity: " & act


nextcell:
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Do Until ActiveCell.EntireRow.Hidden = False
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop
Next I

Set objCol = Nothing

Set objRow = Nothing

Set objDoc = Nothing

Set objWord = Nothing


End Sub
```